# Write issue in file after invoking 'sed -i' command

Tags: shell, sed

I am invoking following command in my logs file(FileName - LogFileName).

```
sed -i '/pattern/,+1d' LogFileName
```

In above log file(LogFileName), application is also continuously writing logs. But after invoking above command, logs written by application are not appending in file(LogFileName).
s

Comment: Are you on Mac? Try `sed -i.bak '' '/pattern/,+1d' LogFileName`

Comment: If you are editing a log file that is open by your Application's log writer then writer will fail to write after editing.

Comment: @anubhava... than what can be the solution, I want to delete some line in logs and save that log file.

Comment: Usually more than one process writing same file is very tricky. Why do you want to delete lines within same file. Can you not make a copy and do your editing/searching.